# "Get Quotes" returns no Error if there are no rates avaliable

Tags: shipping, quote, shipping-address, usps

It's always a good approach to show any result (negative or positive) to the user.

In my case, when I click on the 'Get quotes' button on **My Cart** page and rates are available — it's OK.

But when there is NO rates available for that address, I need to show to customer something like 'Hey, no rates dude'.

As far as I understand, I need to dig in the `estimatePostAction` method and check the rates manually and set some flash-message.

But I'm just wondering about is there another Magento-way to have this approach?

Thanks for any suggestion or vision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, finally I resolved this problem.

But I used not the CartController due to [this issue](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/514523/), but the observer `sales_quote_collect_totals_after`.

Answer (score 1):

I just use something similar to:

```
<?php $_shippingRateGroups = $this->getShippingRates(); ?>
<?php if (!$_shippingRateGroups): ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Sorry, no shipping quotes are available to this address. Please contact us at ' . Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone') . ' for a shipping quote') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
    ...success message...
```

and our getshippingrates function looks something like this:

```
 public function getShippingRates()
{
    if (empty($this->_rates)) {
        $this->getAddress()->collectShippingRates()->save();
        $groups = $this->getAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
        /**
        * If no shipping rate is found an error report will be logged containing product and customer information.
        */
        if (empty($groups)) {
            $this->noShipRateError();
        }
        return $this->_rates = $groups;
    }
    return $this->_rates;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is that applicable to My Cart page?

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  I thought you were talking about shipping quotes from the checkout page.  Either way you could create a simple boolean that will check the saved quote after the request is made and then echo a <div> onto the page based upon results.

Comment: hmm, good point. Let me try this case. I'll let you know.